# Indexed access type to instantiate a Map in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, strong-typing

I'm having trouble reasoning about the following behaviour in Typescript, for a data normalization script. Say I have a `Relations` type with the following shape:

```js
export interface Relations {
  members: Map<string, MemberEntity>;
  users: Map<string, UserEntity>;
  books: Map<string, BookEntity>;
}
```

It follows that a `Partial<Relations>` type makes the properties of that interface optional.

I want to be able to arbitrarily create a new map of the correct type, for each relation property, and then to be able to add the correct type of value to the map (i.e. `MemberEntity`, `UserEntity`, or `BookEntity`).

Here's what I have so far:

```js
private addRelation<K extends keyof Relations>(relationList: Partial<Relations>, relationKey: K, dataToAdd): void {
    relationList[relationKey] = new Map<string, Relations[K]>();
}
```

However, the typescript compiler complains about this:

```
TS2322: Type 'Map<string, Relations[K]>' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Relations>[K]'.
Type 'Map<string, Relations[K]>' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, MemberEntity> & Map<string, UserEntity> & Map<string, BookEntity>.
```

How can I solve this? It looks like I'll need to narrow the types at some point (given the `&`), but I'm curious as to how I can at least tell the compiler the type of the value of the `Map`, given the type arguments and constraints I've provided to the `addRelation` function in the first place.

Comment: This is probably one of those situations where it is okay to cast inside the function body. Sometimes TypeScript does not have the expressive power that we would like it to have. In this case, it might be impossible and casting inside the function with `as Record[K]` is reasonable.

Comment: If use your final parameter `dataToAdd`, typed `:Relations[K]` it works perfectly fine.